# auto-dect the formats HEX to RGB or RGB to HEX

Tags: javascript

Write a function that converts HEX to RGB.

Then Make that function auto-dect the formats

so that if you enter HEX color format it returns RGB

and if you enter RGB color format it returns HEX.

E.G.:

Enter "#0033ff" output rgb(0,15,255)

Enter (0,15,255) output "#0033ff"

Tried the following function to create the result:

```js
   function rgbToHexAndHextorgb(input1, input2, input3) {
    if(!input2){
     //HEX
     let hex = input1;
      var shorthandRegex = input1;
         input1 = input1.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
          return r + r + g + g + b + b;
        });

    var result = [];
    result.push(input1[2]+input1[3]);
    result.push(input1[4]+input1[5]);
    result.push(input1[6]+input1[7]);

    return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
} : null;
}
else
 {
     //RGB
   let r = input1;
   let g = input2;
   let b = input3;
   const componentToHex=(c)=>{
    var hex2 = c.toString(16);
       return hex2.length == 1 ? "0" + hex2 : hex2;
   }
   return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
 
   }
 }
   rgbToHexAndHextorgb(0, 51, 255) ;//"#0033ff"
   rgbToHexAndHextorgb("#0033ff");//(0,51,255)
```

Comment: sorry,my bad.I 'll add some code

Comment: A lot of what's wrong here is simple typos and inconsistent capitalization.  `componetToHex(c)=>{` should be `componentToHex = (c) =>{` for example, and there are some spots where you typed "rbg" instead of "rgb".  Open the developer console and look at the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

You can prepare a function with 3 parameter right away.

```
function rgbToHexAndHextorgb(input1, input2, input3) {
    if(!input2) {
        // HEX
        console.log('hex');
        let hex = input1;
    }
    else {
        // RGB
        console.log('rgb')
        let red = input1;
        let green = input2;
        let blue = input3;
    }
}

// Testing
rgbToHexAndHextorgb(1,2,3)
rgbToHexAndHextorgb('#000000')
```

Comment: so you mean use (r,g,b) instead of input?

Comment: I mean, prepare 3 parameters by default. But if you are sending HEX string, then you know the other 2 parameters wont be used. So r = HEX.

Comment: I changed the answer to your "input"-style

Comment: OK,i do what you said.What wrong with my const componetToHex(c)?

Comment: Herm, if you do a function and expect a value, then you must return something from inside a function.